# Sounds comes out of both headset and speakers

Tags: 12.04, sound

Ubuntu 12.04 is Great except sound problems.

this issue is common , sound comes out the headset and speakers at the same time , i have tried to find a solution through forums , internet .......but not yet able to fix that !

it's so annoying and it's the only reason keeping me from using 12.04.

Any fix soon ?

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring levels with alsamixer or gnome-alsamixer. The sliders you get depend of which sound card / ALSA driver you are using but there's usually a "master" and a "headset" sliders that you can use individually. After you setup your levels, you can make them default with alsactl store.

Also, if you do work with audio or video production, you want to look at using [Jack](http://jackaudio.org/) instead of PulseAudio (or use both). The easiest way to set it up in my experience is using [KXStudio](http://kxstudio.sourceforge.net/Documentation%3aUbuntu%3aUpgrade)'s packages.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this going on with my Sony VPCZ114GX, there is a workaround posted for my model at this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/960124 Basically involves loading up David Henninsson's hda-jack-retask from his ppa at https://launchpad.net/~diwic/+archive/hda and then try Wouter van der Graaf's workaround on comment #7.

As for getting the model of your sound card, I tried the below. Although the problem may be that your machine doesn't know what model to use for sound in the first place.

Found with: $ aplay -l ** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ** card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC889 Analog [ALC889 Analog] ...

Then to get the model to put in alsa-base.conf: $ gunzip -c /usr/share/doc/alsa-base/driver/HD-Audio-Models.txt.gz |grep -i "alc889" intel-alc889a Intel IbexPeak with ALC889A intel-x58 Intel DX58 with ALC889